# Netbeans autocomplete not working on new projects

Tags: javascript, netbeans, autocomplete

I've been working in Netbeans for about 6 months now, everything was working fine.... this morning however, I started a new project and for some reason there is no way to make cross-file autocomplete work.

I defined some global variables in one .JS file, some functions as well.

In another .JS file I try to reference the global or to call a functions, auto complete does not work. Heck I write the function down completely and properly and when I ctrl + click it, it will not take me to the declaration.

Both files are in the same project, both are linked to my Index.html.

I tried deleting the cache, didn't work.
I opened older projects (ones I worked on last week) and both the global variables and the functions that are written cross-files are visible....

Any clue what to do?

**EDIT:** Apparently there is issues with file names. If the name of the file is "config", "config2", "aaaaaconfig" the **Navigator** does not recognize anything in it as declared content... if I name the exact same file "blabla" it starts working... rename it to "config" again and it stops again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after dangling with this for a long time, I've figured it out.... apparently the .js file must NOT have "config" in it's name. Putting it as answer so that others might find it. It is possible that this issue comes with any language, which is why most PHP coders have issues.... BDConfig is a pretty standard name for a PHP file for DB connections.